# c++ 2 Constructor 1 Object, How to?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I have to set up an object and, after an user chose, i have to change some param into the object but not every each.

example:
{

```
class Champ 
{
private: 
       int hp;
       std::string class;
public:
       Champ();
       Champ(std::string chose);
};

Champ::Champ() {hp=10; class="";}

Champ::Champ(std::string chose) {class = chose;}


main()
{
     Champ Test;
     std::string chose;

     getline(cin,chose);

     Test(chose);

return 0;

}
```

this code give me an error.
i need `hp` equal for all "Champ" created but `class` can be changed.

The `hp` can't be "const" because this value may undergo changes...

how can i do this? :/

Comment: get rid of `Champ Test;` and change `Test(chose);` to `Champ Test(chose);`

Comment: Also `class` is a reserved keyword and you cannot have a member named `class`

Comment: the sintaxis you would change Champ Test for Champ test; and later when you call again test(); you invocate again the constructor (an error), you will would define a method like changeHp(int newHp) where you change hp.

Comment: It looks like you are attempting to call the constructor twice for the same object.  Constructors are meant to only ever be called once and are designed to put the object in a valid state after memory is reserved.  What you probably want is a simple member function to later set the value.  Try changing your second constructor to a member function `void SetClass(std::string value)` and calling `Test.SetClass(chose)` instead.  Also and as NathanOliver stated, `class` is a keyword and is probably giving you issues as well.

Comment: Thank you all. @DanielT ur solution is running, thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments in the code below should explain what is going on well enough...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Champ {
    int hp;
    std::string job;

public:
    Champ():
        hp(10) { } // don't need to explicitly initialize `job` because the default constructor for string does what we want.

    explicit Champ(const std::string& choose):
        hp(10),
        job(choose) { }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    using namespace std;

    // this is most like how you had it with the compile error fixed.
    {
        Champ test; // this creates a Champ object using the default constructor

        string choose;
        getline(cin, choose);

        test = Champ(choose); // this creates a new Champ object and assigns it to test... Throwing away the one that was created earlier.
    }

    // this is, imho, a better way to do it:
    {
        string choose;
        getline(cin, choose);

        auto test = Champ(choose); // declare the variable as late as possible, and after you have all the data for its construction. That way, you only make one of them.
    }

    return 0;
}
```